# SQL Server fire off a web request

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Do to some constraints with a client's system and setup, I am wondering if it is possible for SQL Server to fire off a web request?

I need to be able to send emails after a sql server column gets updated. I had a trigger with database mail but the database server on the client won't allow that. The alternative would have that figure fire off a web request when ready. I would do it via a web service on the web server and have it just poll the table, but that seems like a lot of wasteful cycles.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi - That's a question I've asked myself many times over many versions (I've been with MSSQL since 6.5) ... and, last time I checked, "polling" was still the best answer :(  I'm hopeful that .Net integration might be a good solution in newer versions of MSSQL.  But I assure you, firing off COM/ActiveX objects from a SQL trigger definitely *wasn't* (in MSSQL2000 or lower) :(

Comment: THat kinda sucks, I'm looking into SQL CLR Web requests now

Comment: I'm definitely curious if CLR works for you.  It should - and I'm hoping it does :)

Comment: I used a SQL CLR to fire a web request, then the web server sent the email

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can execute managed code from SQL server.  Create a windows service and let that do whatever you want in C# to fulful your need and SQL server call it.

Checkout [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19954/Execute-NET-Code-under-SQL-Server-2005) link for sample program

Answer (score 0):

Do **not** call web services from SQLCLR, and especially do not call web services (or send email) via SQLCRL from triggers. There are many reasons why using SQLCLR for external http or smtp access is a bad idea, but doing it from a trigger is horrendous. Just think how will your application behave in a day when the web service responds with a 10 second latency...

You must do the mail interaction from an external application. You should decouple the interaction between your application and the emailer application via a queue. See [Using Tables as Queues](http://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/) for how to use a SQL Server table as a queue. You can enqueue the mailing request directly from your application, or use a stored proc that both inserts the data and enqueue the request, or as the last resort, use a trigger on the table to enqueue the mailing request. You emailer application (a separate service) should monitor this queue and service it by doing the actual email send (or http web request , for the matter).